# Magento 2: quote_address moved to sales_order_address automatically?

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, model

I created two new columns in quote_address and sales_order_address as shown below. When I first land on checkout, I manually (in the database using Sequel Pro) added '999' into the quote_address custom column 'custom_module_table_id' and then proceeded to checkout successfully.

Unfortunately, the data '999' wasn't automatically copied over into my new column in sales_order_address. Am I missing something? Do I need to make Magento aware that there's more data for it to copy across, or should the above have worked?

```
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('quote_address'),
        'custom_module_table_id',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => true,
            'default' => null,
            'comment' => 'Custom Table Id'
        ]
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order_address'),
        'custom_module_table_id',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => true,
            'default' => null,
            'comment' => 'Custom Table Id'
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Have you do any code to copy data from quote_address to sales_order_address?

Comment: No other code, I presumed Magento automatically copied over the contents of quote_address to sales_order_address?

Comment: I post answer, you need to do that things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy manually in plugin on \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress::convert.

For examples, see Magento plugins (EE only unfortunately):

- \Magento\GiftRegistry\Model\Plugin\ConvertQuoteAddressToOrderAddress::afterConvert
- \Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Model\Plugin\ConvertQuoteAddressToOrderAddress::afterConvert

Reason for this is populateWithArray:

```
$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
    $orderAddress,
    array_merge($orderAddressData, $data),
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface::class
);
```

that looses all data that is not in interface.

```
public function afterConvert(
    QuoteToOrderAddress $subject,
    OrderAddressInterface $result,
    QuoteAddress $quoteAddress,
    $data = []
) {
    if ($quoteAddress->getData('custom_module_table_id')) {
        $result->setData('custom_module_table_id', $quoteAddress->getData('custom_module_table_id'));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do code in your custom extension `fieldset.xml`.

```
app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/fieldset.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
  <scope id="global">
      <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
       <field name="custom_module_table_id">
          <aspect name="to_order"/>
       </field>
      </fieldset>
      </scope>
</config>
```

Comment: If it help you then accept it, So it will help other in community as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I looked online and found the below. Apparently, it no longer works to use the fieldset.xml?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/77016/copy-custom-data-from-quote-to-order-and-order-item-once-order-is-placed-in-mage